# Trait not found error magento2

Tags: php, magento2

I am installing a module, where I am getting the error when 
running

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

The error is like:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'Niks\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\SliderTrait' 
not found in /var/www/clients/client2/web202/web/app/code/NIKS
/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Decimal.php on line 10
```

When I check the `Decimal.php` the code is like

```
<?php
namespace Niks\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal as CoreDecimal;

/**
 * Layer attribute filter
 */
class Decimal extends CoreDecimal
{
    use SliderTrait; //This is relevant line 10 referred in code
...
```

and in the file `SliderTrait.php` it is like:

```
<?php

namespace Niks\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

trait SliderTrait
{
    /** @var \Niks\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection|null  */
    protected $_skipFilterCollection;

...
```

so to me the code looks okay and am not able to find any issue, why this error is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that your vendor folder name is "NIKS", compared to the vendor namespace "Niks". It seems like Magento 2 folder structure is case sensitive inside `/app/code` for autoloading classes. Either change the namespace to "NIKS", or the folder name to "Niks". That should solve it!

Comment: You are absolutely right. correcting that resolved the issue.